# WinHttpCrackUrl failed with 87 error

Tags: c++, http

```
URL_COMPONENTS urlComp;
LPCWSTR pwszUrl1 = 
  L"http://search.msn.com/results.asp?RS=CHECKED&FORM=MSNH&v=1&q=wininet";
DWORD dwUrlLen = 0;

// Initialize the URL_COMPONENTS structure.
ZeroMemory(&urlComp, sizeof(urlComp));
urlComp.dwStructSize = sizeof(urlComp);

// Set required component lengths to non-zero 
// so that they are cracked.
urlComp.dwSchemeLength    = (DWORD)-1;
urlComp.dwHostNameLength  = (DWORD)-1;
urlComp.dwUrlPathLength   = (DWORD)-1;
urlComp.dwExtraInfoLength = (DWORD)-1;

// Crack the URL.
if (!WinHttpCrackUrl( pwszUrl1, (DWORD)wcslen(pwszUrl1), 0, &urlComp))
{
    printf("Error %u in WinHttpCrackUrl.\n", GetLastError());
}
```

This WinHttpCrackUrl api failed with 87(invalid param) on Win7( OS ) please any one suggest a solution or how can i decode my URL in an Easy way in server side ?.Also i want to know how can i distinguish %20 from encoded URL and actual data present in the URL. Example: localhost:8080\Server\search?value="value%20"

Comment: Quote: "This WinHttpCrackUrl api failed with" and then the sentence just stops and you ask for a solution. What does it fail with?

Comment: If you check the official [error reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms681382%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), you will see that error `87` is `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` ("The parameter is incorrect."). So one of the arguments to the function is not correct.

Comment: The code snippet works well, perhaps you have different (invalid) argument in your real scenario.

Comment: No am using this same Codes in my app in Windows 7.Also i want to know how can i distinguish %20 from encoded URL and actual data present in the URL. Example: http://localhost:8080\Server\search?value="value%20"

Comment: Would it be fair to assume that `WinHttpOpen` was called somewhere before this code?

Comment: Its just a snippet from MSDN-WinHttpCrackUrl,

Answer (score 0):

Sets required component lengths to expected value.

All to zero if doesn't need to crack.

```
urlComp.dwSchemeLength    = (DWORD)0;
urlComp.dwHostNameLength  = (DWORD)0;
urlComp.dwUrlPathLength   = (DWORD)0;
urlComp.dwExtraInfoLength = (DWORD)0;
```

Or

```
std::wstring urlHost;
urlHost.resize(url.size());

urlComp.dwHostNameLength = (DWORD)urlHost.size();
urlComp.lpszHostName = &urlHost[0];
```

Comment: Thanks for the post! It would be nice if you could add in simple words what this code does (and maybe a link to the API?)